# Filtering events using OnEventActivity

Tags: json, botframework

I'm trying to filter custom events using adaptive dialogs. It seems that filtering by name does not work. All the events will trigger the actions listed here, but I'd only need to be triggered by one specific event. I tried to implement this based on the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.adaptive.conditions.oneventactivity?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable).

```json
    {
      "$kind": "Microsoft.OnEventActivity",
      "event": "CustonEventName",
      "actions": [
        {
          "$kind": "Microsoft.SendActivity",
          .....
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question? Please have a look at this handy guide to see the steps you can take to get a better answer faster: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you still working on this?

Comment: Please provide some code snippets to help us understand how you have this set up and what exactly the issue is. Generally when my onEvent handler is invoked, I check first for `context.activity.name` to check the specific event and then run my event-specific code.